# Use default options when compiling ports

Tags: freebsd, compile, arguments, freebsd-ports

I am compiling a few ports on FreeBSD, however during the compiling process I am often greeted with options for the dependencies of the port. This causes the compiling process to pause until I select (or in 9/10 cases, just leave the defaults) "OK". This is inconvenient because the compiling process is often long, I would like to walk away from the computer and not worry about having to select options.

I am wondering if there is an argument or compiler flag I can use to automatically use all defaults for dependencies of the port that I am compiling.

I tried to research this, but most likely I was not using the correct terminology in my queries. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `make config-recursive` before make in the port.  This run the interactive config for all dependencies of the port.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use a ports management tool such as [portmaster](http://dougbarton.us/portmaster.html) (available from [/usr/ports/ports-mgmt/portmaster](http://www.freshports.org/ports-mgmt/portmaster)) to install ports: it displays all the configuration screens at the start, and then helpfully collects all the messages (pkg-message) that ports want to display and shows them at the end so you don't miss them in the build output.